If both parent squash are edible can the child squash be toxic?
Assuming contamination from a toxic squash didn't occur, could cross pollination of two edible squashes be toxic?

Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean more clearly. How would the hybrid be produced? Breeding? Genetic manipulation? What kind? Are you thinking of specific, known toxicity that already exists in other cultivars/species? Are you talking about general toxicity, including novel traits?

Hi Dave, thanks for editing your post; I think terdon's comment is very important and I encourage you to read and consider it in its entirely: so far you have only responded to one part of that comment. It might be especially helpful to link to what you've already read about squash toxicity that has led you to ask this question.

easily, see stress induced gene expression in Cucurbitacin
